# Set input manager values at run time in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to set input manager submit and cancel values at run time, something like this:

```
if (condition)
{
    enterButton = KeyCode.Joystick1Button0;
    cancelButton = KeyCode.Joystick1Button1;
}
else
{
    enterButton = KeyCode.Joystick1Button1;
    cancelButton = KeyCode.Joystick1Button0;
}

submitKey = enterButton;
cancelKey = cancelButton;
```

How can i achieve this in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you already have an approach if you were to be using the old `Input` class but now you want to port this to the new Input System

I wouldn't change the buttons themselves at all but rather handle this implementation wise like e.g.

```
yourInputActions.PrimaryButton.performed += () => PrimaryAction;
yourInputActions.SecondaryButton.performed += () => SecondaryAction;
```

and then simply have a switch there

```
private void PrimaryAction()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        DoX();
    }
    else
    {
        DoY();
    }
}

private void SecondaryAction()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        DoY();
    }
    else
    {
        DoX();
    }
}
```

---

Or alternatively of course you can simply add and remove the callbacks accordingly but then you have to call this not all the time but only right in the moment the condition changed and do

```
yourInputActions.PrimaryButton.performed -= PrimaryAction;
yourInputActions.PrimaryButton.performed -= SecondaryAction;
yourInputActions.SecondaryButton.performed -= PrimaryAction;
yourInputActions.SecondaryButton.performed -= SecondaryAction; 

if(condition)
{
    yourInputActions.PrimaryButton.performed += PrimaryAction;
    yourInputActions.SecondaryButton.performed += SecondaryAction;
}
else
{
    yourInputActions.PrimaryButton.performed += SecondaryAction;
    yourInputActions.SecondaryButton.performed += PrimaryAction;
}
```